# When does fit() stop running in scikit?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using `scikit-learn` to train classifiers. I'm particularly using `linear_model.LogisticRegression`. But my question is: what's the stopping criteria for the training?! because I don't see any parameter that indicates the number of epochs!

Also the same for random forests?

Comment: I have very low experience with classifiers but I think there's no actual training limit, you can train them as long as you want and in theory they'll become a bit better each time assuming the data you train them with is correct.

Comment: tol: float, optional : Tolerance for stopping criteria.

Comment: @David yeah I saw this but it doesn't help at all to understand what's going on :/

Comment: The sci-kit documention also links directly the underlying liblinear documentation: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/ If there is any confusion on what is actually going on there, I would recommend shifting over cross-validated since the question will be more methodological than programming related.

Comment: @larsmans do you have any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no hard limit to the number of iterations for `LogisticRegression`; instead it tries to detect convergence with a specified tolerance, `tol`: the smaller `tol`, the longer the algorithm will run.

From the source code, I gather that the algorithms stops when the norm of the objective's gradient is less than `tol` times its initial value, before training started. This is worth documenting.

As for random forests, training stops when `n_estimators` trees have been fit of maximum depth `max_depth`, constrained by the parameters `min_samples_split`, `min_samples_leaf` and `max_leaf_nodes`. Tree learning is completely different from iterative linear model learning.